# Ayuda, con este codigo de arbol de busqueda "bad operand types for binary operator '-' first type: String; second type: int"

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintStream p=System.out;

        CArbolBinarioDeBusqueda arbolbb=new CArbolBinarioDeBusqueda();


        String matricula;
        String marca;
        String modelo;
        String propietario;
        int i=0,cod,op,res;

        p.println("Introducir datos. Finalizar con Ctrl+Z");

        p.println("Matricula: ");
        while((matricula=in.readLine())!=null)
        {
            p.println("Marca: ");
            marca=String.valueOf(in.readLine());
            cod=arbolbb.insertar(new CDatos(matricula, marca, modelo, propietario));

            if(cod==CArbolBinarioDeBusqueda.YA_EXISTE)
            {
                if((marca>=0)) //en esta parte me sale mal, bad operand types for binary operator '-' first type: String;      second type: int
                {
                    CDatos datos=(CDatos)   arbolbb.buscar(new CDatos(matricula,marca,modelo,propietario));
                    datos.asignarMarca(marca);
                }
                else
                {
                    arbolbb.borrar(new CDatos(matricula,marca,modelo,propietario))  ;
                    p.println("Nodo borrado");
                }

            }
            p.println("Matricula: ");
        }
        p.println("\n");

        do
        {
            p.println("\nArbol: ");
            p.println("MENU DE RECORRIDOS");
            p.println("\n1. Recorrido Inorden ");
            p.println("\n2. Recorrido Preorden ");
            p.println("\n3. Recorrido Postorden ");

            p.println("\n4. Salir ");
            p.println("\nSeleccione un tipo de recorrido: ");
            op=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

            switch(op)
            {
                case 1:
                    p.println("\nRecorrido Inorden ");
                    arbolbb.visitarInorden();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    p.println("\nRecorrido Preorden ");
                    arbolbb.visitarPreorden();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    p.println("\nRecorrido Postorden ");
                    arbolbb.visitarPostorden();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default: p.println("Opción invalida...");
                    break;

            }   
            p.println("\nDesea continuar (1/2): ");
            res=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        }while(res!=2);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que se supone que se tendría que almacenar en marca? ¿Un número?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Java no permite comparar un int con un String, principalmente por eso te sale el error, Lo que podrías hacer es convertir primero ese String a Int con

```
Integer.parseInt(marca).
```

O también si solo quieres saber si trae datos puedes hacerle al String:

```
if((marca>=0)) //sustituye esto por
if(!marca.isEmpty())
```

tu pregunta no está claro lo que necesitas ejecutar en esa línea que es lo que hace para poderte ayudar más

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por comentar mi primer post! me funciono if(!marca.isEmpty()) @Ajeno

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que realizar la conversión de  `String` a `Int` mediante `Integer.parseInt()` para que puedas realizar la operación ya que estas realizando una comparación entre dos tipos diferentes.

Cambia de

```
if((marca>=0))
{
```

hacia:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(marca)>=0)
{
```

---

Existe otra situación importante a considerar, en la cual el valor de la variable `marca` pudiera no tener un valor numérico. por la cual te aconsejo agregar un método para realizar dicha validación.

```
public static boolean esNumerico(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

Usaríamos de esta forma el método:

```
if((esNumerico(marca)?Integer.parseInt(marca):0)>=0)//Donde :0 define un valor default 0 en caso de la variable no contener un valor numérico.
```