# ¿porque me sale este error? bad operand types for binary operator "-" firs type:String second type: String

Tags: java

¿es que me sale el siguiente error y no entiendo porque me sale?
ME SALE

> "bad operand types for binary operator "-""

hay especifico con una flechita el error.gracias

```
class triangulo {

    public void creartriangulo(int a, String b, String c) {
          if(c.length()==a){
          System.out.println(""+c);

          }
           else{
             System.out.println(""+c);
             c-= b; -----> este es el error
             c= (c-b); ----> así tampoco me sale ("pero cuando ponga el + si me sirve")

             creartriangulo(a,b,c);


        }
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos lo que intentas hacer en esa línea? `b` y `c` son del tipo  String, no puedes hacer una operación matemática con esos valores.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Ayuda, con este codigo de arbol de busqueda "bad operand types for binary operator '-' first type: String; second type: int"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31387/ayuda-con-este-codigo-de-arbol-de-busqueda-bad-operand-types-for-binary-operat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es simple, no puedes hacer operaciones matemáticas a una variable de tipo `string` y en tu código `c` y `b` son de ese tipo por lo que siempre te mandara ese error, tienes la opción ya sea de cambiarlo a tipo `int` o hacer una conversión de la variable y devolver el valor.

**Cambio a int**

```
class triangulo {

public void creartriangulo(int a, int b, int c) {
      if(c==a){
      System.out.println(""+c);

      }
       else{
         System.out.println(""+c);
         c-= b;

         creartriangulo(a,b,c);
      }

  }
}
```

**Conversión de variables**

```
class triangulo {

public void creartriangulo(int a, String b, String c) {
      if(c.length()==a){
      System.out.println(""+c);

      } else {
         System.out.println(""+c);
         int parseInt = Integer.parseInt(c);
         parseInt -= Integer.parseInt(b);

         creartriangulo(a,b,Integer.toString(parseInt);
      }
  } 
}
```